# Building ANTs using Cmake in a Conda environment?

Tags: linux, cmake

I recently have been trying to use Cmake to build ANTs (https://github.com/ANTsX/ANTs).

I am installing it on CentOS07, and am attempting this install in an Anaconda environment, as I do not have root permissions to install the proper dependencies in my bash.

There is a good tutorial I am following (https://www.greydongilmore.com/post/wsl_docs/ants/), but seem to run into some issues.

Does anybody have advice about the correct environment and dependencies I could use to install ANTs into my conda environment?

*FYI I made this question just so I could answer it...took me about 2 weeks to solve and I don't want someone to go through what I did.

Comment: Please describe in the question what you've done and what went wrong. Pointing to the tutorial only tells us, what you meant to do, not what you actually did, and we don't know what happened --- what are "some issues"? Please see [ask].

Comment: Robert, I specifically described that I created this question so I could answer it myself and possibly help someone in the future. Please revoke your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...so this install is a bit tricky...but it totally can be done with the right dependencies.

First you want to set up your Anaconda environment. I did all the installs on the conda forge channel. First Install you want to do is Cmake.

```
conda install -c conda-forge cmake
```

I was using version 3.22.1, but I think any recent version should be fine.

You can check if you are pointing to your correct cmake by typing `which cmake`. This should print the path to cmake in your environment bin. You can also check the version with `cmake --version`.

Next, you need to install the GCC compiler.

`conda install -c conda-forge gcc`

This should install in your environment bin as well. I was using GCC V 11.2.0, so try that one if you have issues.

Now this is where Cmake is going to yell at you...although you have GCC 11.2.0 installed it will say ERROR: GCC 5.1. or later is required. This is because YOU ALSO NEED TO INSTALL THE G++ COMPILER. DO THIS WITH THE COMMAND BELOW.

`conda install -c conda-forge gxx`

If that doesn't install, try...

`conda install -c anaconda gxx_linux-64`

Now you should be able to get through most of you make. This is where I got stuck...I kept getting an error at [100%]. Cmake errors are shit so it says Error 1, Error 2 and all this garbage...but also should provide the error undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'. This is because your GCC/G++ compilers are not compatible with the current GLIB. I found the answer to this here (https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues/3620)...

But basically you need to install sysroot into your conda environment with your command below.

`conda install -c conda-forge sysroot_linux-64=2.17`

For me this all worked, and I was able to complete the make with this environment setup.

You may need to play around with different versions of gcc,g++, and sysroot.

Feel free to PM with any questions if anyone has an issue...this took me a long time to figure out so I wanted to try and save someone a headache!!